# Mongodb: aggregate $match only if object is empty

Tags: mongodb

I want to `$match` only the empty objects in my `aggregate()`. Is it possible? I know of `$exists`, but `{}`'s boolean value is `true`, so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried to just use `{field: {}}` ?

For example:

```
db.users.aggregate([{$match: {val: {}}}])
```

Comment: Thanks, easier than I thought.

Comment: How can I do the opposite and match only no empty result ?